# Can you call app.get() from a function within nodeJS (Express)

Tags: node.js, express

So im currently doing a little side project, and was playing around with nodeJS, was wondering whether you could call a function from within a HTTP post method and then that function calls a get request.

```
app.post('/otherEndpoint', (req,res) => {
    var title = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    myFunction(title);

});


function myFunction(title){

    app.get(`/someEndpoint${title}`, (req,res) => {
      console.log(res);
});
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the method you provided in your question you could use a variable as `cache` and [`params`](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/express/params).

Example:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

let cache = {
    titles: []
}

app.post('/otherEndpoint', function(req, res) {
    var title = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    (cache.titles).push({ title, timestamp: new Date().getTime() });
});
app.get(`/someEndpoint/:title`, function(req, res) {
    let found = false;
    cache.titles.forEach(object => {
        if (object.title == req.params.title && object.timestamp > (new Date().getTime() - 10000)) { // Title is equal to the tile in the URL and the title was created less than 10 seconds ago
            res.send('title exists');
            found = true;
        }
    });
    if (!found) { // If the title was not found
        res.send('title doesn\'t exist or was creates more than 10 seconds ago');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit: Full demo walkthrough

Install dependencies

```
$ yarn add express body-parser
```

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/create', (req,res) => {
  var title = req.body.title;
  myFunction(title);
  res.end('ok');
});


function myFunction(title){

  app.get(`/SE${title}`, (req,res) => {
    res.end(title);
  });
  console.log(`created route SE${title}`);
}

app.listen(3000);
```

Now run your script:

```
$ node index
```

And in another terminal, let's try it:

let's try to `/GET SEyeah`

```
$ curl localhost:3000/SEyeah
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /SEyeah</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

it's a 404. Now let's create it first :

```
$ curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '{"title": "yeah"}' localhost:3000/create
ok
```

(at this point in the node process you should have "created route SEyeah")

Now let's try that first route again :

```
$ curl localhost:3000/SEyeah
yeah
```

Voila :)!

#### Original answer

Protip: when you wonder if something would work, try it. You're not going to set your computer on fire with JavaScript.

Yes that should work. If the function is declared in a different file, you can simply pass the app as a parameter :

```js
app.post('/otherEndpoint', (req,res) => {
  var title = JSON.stringify(req.body);
  myFunction(app, title);
});


function myFunction(app, title){
  app.get(`/someEndpoint${title}`, (req,res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

I have to give this disclaimer though: this sounds like an awful idea and you're probably better off doing something like this instead:

```js
app.get(`/someEndpoint/:title`, (req,res) => {
  // Check if req.params.title is a valid title otherwise send a 404.
  res.end(req.params.title);
});
```

Comment: Ahah, thanks, yeah i have been trying it, but i just picked up that, im pretty novice with js, node is just easy to understand, but do you have to parse "app" through the function? If so that may be my main error, Thanks again!

Comment: you only have to if app is not in the scope. If you're working within the same file and app is globally defined then your code from the question works. Your problem might be around `JSON.stringify(req.body)`. Try to console.log it, make sure you don't have forbidden chars and at least see what route you're creating before accessing it

Comment: Yeah I had a doubt but I just tried it, it works. I'm updating the answer for the full demo

Comment: I don't understand your second question